# Unable to authorize access to a Service Bus Namespace for service running as LocalSystem or NetworkService?

Tags: servicebus

I'm using Service Bus For Windows Server v1.0. I have a service which is running in the LocalSystem (NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM) account or NetworkService (NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE). I want to give that service manage rights on the default namespace in service bus.

I've run:

```
set-sbnamespace -name ServiceBusDefaultNamespace -ManageUsers 
"NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM","NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE","MY_DOMAIN\MY_USER"
```

With the result:

```
Name                  : ServiceBusDefaultNamespace
AddressingScheme      : Path
CreatedTime           : 7/19/2013 2:40:52 PM
IssuerName            : ServiceBusDefaultNamespace
IssuerUri             : ServiceBusDefaultNamespace
ManageUsers           : {nt authority\system, nt authority\network service,
                    my_user@my_domain}
```

But when trying to create a Queue, I get the error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized. Authorization 
failed for specified action: Manage..TrackingId:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX, 
TimeStamp:7/23/2013 9:31:31 AM
```

If I try to add the System Account "MY_DOMAIN\MY_SERVER$" it complains that the account doesn't exist even though this works perfectly for MS SQL Server.

If I try to run the service as MY_DOMAIN\MY_USER that works but it's not ideally what I want.

I have tried restarting the server after making the config changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't add computer account "MY_DOMAIN\MY_SERVER$" as "ManageUsers" directly.
Hovever you can set windows group as "ManageUsers",this is full enough.

You just should

- create an group
- add "MY_DOMAIN\MY_SERVER$" computer account to a group
- use this group as "ManageUsers" in Set-SBNamespace powershell command

This is worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

suggest to use shared access key.

To get the connection string with shared access key, run PowerShell cmd:

```
$authRule = Get-SBAuthorizationRule -NamespaceName ServiceBusDefaultNamespace
$authRule[0].ConnectionString
```